# why unnessary scroll bar is appearing on page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I'm using twitter bootstrap for my website.

I see a scroll bar when there is no need of it.

can you you please tell me why it is there.

http://khanawal.com/MYListings.aspx

any help would be appreciated.

regards
Manish

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your body css:

e.g.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
```

This will not fix the problem, it just is a way around it. The reason it has got a scrollbar is that your body element is to big to fit in the page.